# Prove that if $I$ contains a unit, then $I = R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring with identity, $I$ an ideal of $R$. Prove that if $I$ contains a unit, then $I = R$.

I am doing a double containment proof and am stuck with this ($\subseteq$) direction.

**Proof :** Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $I$ an ideal of $R$.

($\supseteq$) Suppose $U\in I$ such that $U$ is a unit. Then $U^{-1}\in R$. So $U\cdot U^{-1} = 1$. Since $U\in I$, $U\cdot U^{-1}\in I$. Thus $1 \in I$. Suppose $a \in R$. Then $a\cdot 1 \in I$. Thus, for every $a \in R$, $I = R$.

($\subseteq$) Suppose

Comment: I mean, $I\subseteq R$ is given.

Comment: Small MathJax tip : when writing an equation you don't have to put each symbol between dollars signs. It's better to write your whole equation with just one dollar at the start and one at then end.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal is (by definition) a subset of a ring.

You only need to show "$\supseteq$" inclusion which you have done correctly.